# Row Level Security in Power BI - not working

Tags: dax, row-level-security

I am trying to implement Row level security into one of my reports and wanted some advice regarding a problem that I am currently facing. I have a table with different departments purchases (based on the data from a survey) so that would contain Department Name, Employee First Name and Last Name, Products, Price. And my second table has "Usernames" for each departments, Department Name, ID and Email address. 
I connected both the tables using their Department Names ( it is a Many to one relationship).And every time I try to click on the "Apply security filter in both directions", I get the following error:
[image]

My DAX expression from the second table to make the row level security work is:
[image]
And it works perfectly when I try to view as using different IDs in the Power BI Desktop, However my report looks completely blank on the server whenever I try to test out a role. Can someone please tell me what am I doing wrong here?
Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you please clarify which is on the one side of the relationship? Also, why is it bidirectional and you want to apply security in both directions?

Answer (score 0):

Do not use bi-directional relationship and do not apply RLS in both directions.